# Como garantir atomicidade transacional em mais de uma Thread concorrente em um ambiente Java SE utilizando o framework Spring?

Tags: java, oracle, spring

Uma solução Java SE, utilizando o framework Spring, está sendo desenvolvida com o intuito de paralelizar a execução de uma Stored Procedure no Oracle 9i, Procedure esta que recebe como parâmetro uma ou mais linhas de um arquivo gigante a ser processado.

Isso será feito por intermédio de um pool de Threads, onde cada Thread invocará essa mesma Stored Procedure passando como parâmetro linhas diferentes deste arquivo, a fim de otimizar o tempo de processamento em comparação à somente uma execução desta Procedure.
Entretanto, é necessário garantir atomicidade transacional sobre todas as execuções/transações desta mesma Procedure, como é garantido hoje em uma única execução desta Procedure — ou seja, commitar as transações no final e somente caso nenhuma outra acuse erro: e caso haja erro em alguma execução de uma Thread, será necessário efetuar rollback em todas as transações das demais.

Foi logicamente cogitado utilizar uma implementação JTA (XA) no Spring, [como aqui](http://spring.io/blog/2011/08/15/configuring-spring-and-jta-without-full-java-ee/), onde cada Thread/transação seria considerada um recurso participante do two-phase commit, porém acredito que o design desta nossa solução fere o princípio do mecanismo JTA, pois a princípio ele somente garante atomicidade sobre os recursos utilizados em um mesmo método transacional, ou seja, em somente uma mesma Thread.

Como garantir isso de uma maneira não programática?

Answer (score 5):

Utilizando apenas o Atomikos, uma implementação do [JTA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Transaction_API) e do [XA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X/Open_XA), fiz um exemplo simples que permite executar processamento em várias threads dentro de uma transação.

O projeto completo está disponível no meu [GitHub](https://github.com/utluiz/threads-with-transaction).

## Implementação

Antes de mais nada, temos a inicialização do `DataSource` e do `TransactionManager`:

```java
// Atomikos implementations
private static UserTransactionManager utm;
private static AtomikosDataSourceBean adsb;

// initialize resources
public static void init() {
    utm = new UserTransactionManager();
    try {
        utm.init();
        adsb = new AtomikosDataSourceBean();
        adsb.setMaxPoolSize(20);
        adsb.setUniqueResourceName("postgres");
        adsb.setXaDataSourceClassName("org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource");
        Properties p = new Properties();
        p.setProperty("user", "postgres");
        p.setProperty("password", "0");
        p.setProperty("serverName", "localhost");
        p.setProperty("portNumber", "5432");
        p.setProperty("databaseName", "postgres");
        adsb.setXaProperties(p);
    } catch (SystemException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Depois, uma *thread* que recebe a instância da transação (`Transaction`) principal:

```java
private static class Processamento implements Callable<Integer> {

    private int id;
    private boolean falhar;
    private Transaction transaction;

    public Processamento(int id, boolean falhar, Transaction transaction) {
        this.falhar = falhar;
        this.transaction = transaction;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer call() throws Exception {
        if (falhar) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Falhou inesperadamente!");
        }

        //enlist xa connection
        XAConnection xac = AtomikosDataSource.getDS().getXaDataSource().getXAConnection();
        synchronized (transaction) {
            transaction.enlistResource(xac.getXAResource());
        }

        //normal execution, update row with OK
        Connection c = xac.getConnection();
        Statement s = c.createStatement();
        s.executeUpdate("update teste set processado = 'ok' where id = " + id);
        s.close();
        c.close();

        //delist xa connection
        synchronized (transaction) {
            transaction.delistResource(xac.getXAResource(), XAResource.TMSUCCESS);
        }
        return id;
    }

}
```

Note que, ao invés de usar o JTA, estou usando diretamente a API do XA implementada pelo Atomikos.

A chamada `AtomikosDataSource.getDS().getXaDataSource().getXAConnection()` recupera uma conexão do XA, a qual é adicionada à transação principal com o comando `transaction.enlistResource(xac.getXAResource())`.

Fiz a sincronização em alguns trechos, pois obtive aleatoriamente alguns `NullPointerException` nos testes, porém isso não deve ser um problema se você usar as conexões com prudência, isto é, sem ficar abrindo-as e fechando-as o tempo todo.

Finalmente, um método que inicia cinco instâncias da *thread* acima:

```java
public static int processar(boolean falhar) {
    int ok = 0;
    Transaction transaction = null;
    try {

        //start transaction
        AtomikosDataSource.getTM().begin();
        transaction = AtomikosDataSource.getTM().getTransaction();

        //create thread pool
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
        List<Callable<Integer>> processos = new ArrayList<Callable<Integer>>();

        //create 5 threads, passing the main transaction as argument
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            processos.add(new Processamento(i + 1, i == 4 && falhar, transaction));
        }

        //execute threads and wait
        List<Future<Integer>> futures = executor.invokeAll(processos);

        //count the result; get() will fail if thread threw an exception
        Throwable ex = null;
        for (Future<Integer> future : futures) {
            try {
                int threadId = future.get();
                System.out.println("Thread " + threadId + " sucesso!");
                ok++; 
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                ex = e;
            }
        }

        if (ex != null) {
            throw ex;
        }

        //finish transaction normally
        transaction.commit();

    } catch (Throwable e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        try {
            //try to rollback
            if (transaction != null) {
                AtomikosDataSource.getTM().rollback();
            }
        } catch (IllegalStateException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SystemException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    return ok;
}
```

Fiz alguns testes tanto num cenário de sucesso quanto de falha para validar o resultado.

No cenário de sucesso, cada uma das cinco *threads* atualiza uma linha da tabela `TESTE` com o valor `ok` e faz o *commit* da transação.

No cenário de falha, a última thread sempre lança uma exceção, forçando o *rollback* das outras quatro *threads*.

Veja o código no GitHub para maiores detalhes.

## Notas sobre a configuração

Usei o PostgreSQL no exemplo. Foi necessário habilitar a configuração `max_prepared_transactions` com um valor maior que zero no arquivo de configuração `postgresql.conf`.

É importante verificar se o seu driver de banco de dados suporta transações distribuídas. Li em algum lugar que o MySQL pode ter alguns problemas quanto a isso.

## Observações

Para fazer o exemplo funcionar com Spring, basta configurar as classes criadas manualmente em beans no XML ou através de anotações. Fica a seu critério.

Cuidado se resolver implementar algo assim dentro de um Servidor de Aplicação, de modo a não interferir nas transações normais do sistema.

Pessoalmente, não vejo uma real necessidade em processamento paralelo dentro de uma mesma transação. É muito mais eficiente dividir o processamento em blocos transacionais. Há várias técnicas para se fazer isso sem tornar o estado do sistema inconsistente, por exemplo, usando colunas adicionais na tabela ou mesmo uma tabela extra.

Comment: Luiz, vc pode não enxergar razão alguma para isso, porém a necessidade, no meu caso e tipicamente em muitos outros, existe e é uma premissa para garantir a consistência dos dados, sem delegar essa responsabilidade a outros mecanismos programáticos de reprocessamento de blocos, muitas vezes definidos como compensating transactions. O protocolo XA, ao contrário do que vc afirmou, garante que uma transação global orquestre outras transações e garanta o estado consistente de uma base de dados.

Comment: @AlbertoFragaláNeto Não afirmei que o XA não faz isso, apenas que não vejo muito sentido nesse contexto. Não sei até hoje de um BD com tamanho volume de dados onde foi necessário manter uma transação e ao mesmo tempo processar em paralelo. Sobre a questão de consistência, não vejo nenhum impedimento em garanti-la por bloco. Pelas experiências que tenho em trabalhar com volume, mantenho minha posição: em geral esse requisito de consistência "tudo ou nada" é desnecessário se o processamento for bem planjado. Algo impede o seu sistema de ter uma flag "processado" para cada bloco?

Comment: @AlbertoFragaláNeto De qualquer forma, vou atualizar a resposta com um projeto de exemplo que fiz.

Comment: Luiz, após vários testes, foi notado que não está ocorrendo o "enlistment" das conexões de cada Thread. As conexões estão sendo commitadas independentemente, no momento em que é invocado o método "executeUpdate". Isso pode ser observado se vc invocar apenas o primeiro teste "sucesso()", e apenas este, e realizar um rollback no TransactionManager ao invés de commit no final. Vc observará todas as linhas atualizadas para "ok". Eu garanti o parâmetro que vc citou, observando no log (INFO: USING com.atomikos.icatch.threaded_2pc = true). O que deve estar ocorrendo?

Comment: Luiz, estive lendo a documentação desse parâmetro que vc me passou, e notei que na verdade ele não realiza isso que vc propôs. A documentação cita que na verdade o processo multi-thread é em relação ao processo de commit do two-phase-commit, para efeitos de performance quando existem muitos recursos envolvidos na transação: (http://www.atomikos.com/Documentation/JtaProperties)

Comment: @AlbertoFragaláNeto Boas notícias. Consegui mexer no projeto agora a noite. Eu realmente me equivoquei quanto ao parâmetro mencionado na resposta anterior. Meu teste de "sucesso" devo ter sido uma coincidência. Fiz o *enlistment* manualmente através da referência ao `Transaction` da thread principal e obtive os resultados que acho que você está procurando. Boa sorte na sua implementação real!

Comment: Luiz, desde ja, muito obrigado pelo tempo despendido! Apenas para concluirmos a questão: temos então a conclusão que não existe uma implementação do JTA que garanta isso de uma maneira não programática?

Comment: @AlbertoFragaláNeto Pode ser que alguma implementação tenha um parâmetro como aquele que a princípio eu havia pensado que fazia isso, mas desconheço uma não programática. Até onde entendo, a própria arquitetura do JTA define o tratamento por threads, já que o padrão de uma requisição por thread é o aplicado em todos os servidores JEE.